# Android. Replace * character from String

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I have a String variable that contains '*' in it. But Before using it I have to replace all this character.

I've tried replaceAll function but without success:

```
text = text.replaceAll("*","");
text = text.replaceAll("*",null);
```

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why not just use [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, that does not take a `regex` as parameter: -

```
text = text.replace("*","");
```

---

In contrary, [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as first parameter, and since `*` is a *meta-character* in regex, so you need to escape it, or use it in a character class. So, your way of doing it would be: -

```
text = text.replaceAll("[*]","");  // OR
text = text.replaceAll("\\*","");
```

But, you really can use simple *replace* here.

Comment: But does it remove all * if String have more than 1 character?

Comment: @arhimed. Yeah, of course it removes all of them. Just try it out on your sample string.

Answer (score 8):

you can simply use  [**String#replace()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
text = text.replace("*","");
```

[**String.replaceAll(regex, str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes regex as a first argument, as `*` is a metachacter you should escape it with a backslash to treat it as a normal charcter.

```
text.replaceAll("\\*", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this.**

You need to escape the `*` for the regular expression, using .

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\*","");
```